# Is there any Mouse click event for TableColumn in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, mouseclick-event, tablecolumn

Is there any Mouse click event for TableColumn in Java FX ?
I can see it in tableView but not in TableColumn. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you want to detect mouse-click on TableCells or on the header?

Comment: I want mouse click event on column header.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particularly nice way to do this. Probably the best option is not to set text on the column, but to set the graphic to a `Label` containing the desired text instead. Then register the mouse listener with the `Label`.

Using the [standard Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) as an example, you could do:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>();
Label firstNameColHeader = new Label("First Name");
firstNameColHeader.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on header"));
firstNameColumn.setGraphic(firstNameColHeader);
```

Note that this will break the [table menu button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#tableMenuButtonVisibleProperty), if you use it, because the options in the menu use the text from the `TableColumn`, which is no longer present.